# Cannot access a non-static member of outer type X via nested type Y

Tags: c#, winforms

The error was too long to type in the title. So this is what it says:

> Error 1   Cannot access a non-static member of outer type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1' via nested type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1.PCPrint'  C:\Users\Andrew\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs  407 39  WindowsFormsApplication3

I am trying to print my form however, it is not recognising the text box, txtName.Text. Why?
Here is the code:

```
        public class PCPrint : System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
        {
            private Font _font;

            private string _text;

            private string TextToPrint
            {
                get { return _text; }
                set { _text = value; }
            }
            public Font PrinterFont
            {
                get { return _font; }
                set { _font = value; }
            }
            public PCPrint()
                : base()
            {
                _text = string.Empty;
            }
            public PCPrint(string str)
                : base()
            {
                _text = str;
            }
            protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnBeginPrint(e);
                if (_font == null)
                {
                    _font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10);
                }
            }
            protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnPrintPage(e);

                int printHeight;
                int printWidth;
                int leftMargin;
                int rightMargin;
                Int32 lines;
                Int32 chars;
                {
                    printHeight = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height -
                        base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
                    printWidth = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width -
                        base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right;
                    leftMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left;
                    rightMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right;
                }
                if (base.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape)
                {
                    int tmp;
                    tmp = printHeight;
                    printHeight = printWidth;
                    printWidth = tmp;
                }
                Int32 numLines = (int)printHeight / PrinterFont.Height;

                RectangleF printArea = new RectangleF(leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight);

                StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit);

                e.Graphics.MeasureString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, new SizeF(printWidth, printHeight), format, out chars, out lines);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, Brushes.Black, printArea, format);

                curChar += chars;

                if (curChar < _text.Length)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                    curChar = 0;
                }
            }
            public int RemoveZeros(int value)
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return value;
                }

            }
            public void PrintDocument()
            {
                PCPrint printer = new PCPrint();
                printer.PrinterFont = new Font("Verdana", 10);
                printer.TextToPrint = txtName.Text; //ERROR IS HERE
                printer.Print();
            }

            private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              PrintDocument();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough code posted for us to solve this.

Comment: Im afraid that is all the code i have :/

Comment: That was sarcasm, I think. You've posted far too much code here for us to wade through; the error message gives you a specific line number. Trim the code as much as possible, to the minimal amount needed to produce the problem. Expecting us to review 100 lines of code when you have an exact location is a little much. (You have one area that uses `txtName.Text` - where is `txtName` declared in relation to that location?)

Comment: Please see [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/). Better to provide a minimal code example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @BradM I guess you should avoid using such a sarcastic comment on a newbie question.

Comment: Sorry im new to this website, i did try that a few minutes ago but people said i did't have enough code. Okay, ill try again. Thanks

Comment: can you tell us which line is line 407?

Comment: @SamIam - It does have `//ERROR IS HERE` next to it.

Comment: Line 407 is the beginning of Public Void Print Document. The exact error location is marked with a comment

Comment: Actually, you have two. If you look at the second one and the class that code is in, you should be able to see where the problem is located. (Hint: What class is `txtName` declared in, and what class is the error located in?)

Comment: Good thing you included all the `using` declarations, those are totally relevant

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry man, i wish i could figure it out on my own. But this one i just need spelling out to me :(

Comment: You've cut out the definition of the `txtName` variable entirely... Try to trim down what you post so that *everything relevant* is contained, but nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You have a nested class:

`public class PCPrint : System.Drawing.PrintDocument`

Inside this nested class, you are trying to **directly** access a member of the `Form`, `txtName.Text`, which I am assuming is a textbox.

More importantly, why nest the class? Put it in another file.

Secondly, why is PCPrint making an instance of itself instead of calling it's own members?

Thirdly, PCPrint might be better off being static or a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

You could pass the string to `PrintDocument()` if it is called in the `Form`.

```
public void PrintDocument(string textName)
{
  PrinterFont = new Font("Verdana", 10);
  TextToPrint = textName; // No longer trying to magically access field
  Print();
}
```

Then in your form, hook it up to your button event handler. (Do one of these three depending on what you decide to do with the class).

```
private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PCPrint.PrintDocument(txtName.Text); // If static

  PCPrint printer = new PCPrint();
  printer.PrintDocument(txtName.Text); // If not static

  PCPrint.GetInstance().PrintDocument(txtName.Text); // If singleton
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`txtName` doesn't appear to be a member of the `PCPrint` class, but you're treating it like one.

Even though `PCPrint` is inside your `Form1` class, they are still different classes, and they instantiate into different objects.

---

As for the solution to your problem ... I think you need to re-think your architecture.

I suppose it makes sense that you want an object to represent a print document, but it shouldn't directly interact with button click events.

Instead it should be created and/or invoked from an event, and you can pass your textbox.text in to the constructor or something.

Comment: Okay, how would i be able to begin printing my text boxes then? Im really sorry, im just new to C#

Comment: @AndrewKilburn It's hard to say, I've been reviewing your code as best I can, and I'm having trouble figuring out what a `PCPrint` is and why you need one to print your textbox text

Comment: If there is another way to print my text boxes and you know a website or so that could help me, i would greatly appreciate it. After all, that is how i found the guide to create PCPrint. -thanks

Comment: You can pass the value of txtName.Text as parameter of the method PrintDocument